# change format of python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary in this format:

```
{('first', 'negative'): 57, ('first', 'neutral'): 366, ('first', 'positive'): 249, ('second', 'negative'): 72, ('second', 'neutral'): 158, ('second', 'positive'): 99, ('third', 'negative'): 156, ('third', 'neutral'): 348, ('third', 'positive'): 270}
```

I want to convert it to:

```
{'first': [{'sentiment':'negative', 'value': 57}, {'sentiment': 'neutral', 'value': 366}, {'sentiment': 'positive', 'value': 249}], 'second': [{'sentiment':'negative', 'value': 72}, {'sentiment': 'neutral', 'value': 158}, {'sentiment': 'positive', 'value': 99}], 'third': [{'sentiment':'negative', 'value': 156}, {'sentiment': 'neutral', 'value': 348}, {'sentiment': 'positive', 'value': 270}]}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to show some effort on your part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
o = {('first', 'negative'): 57, ('first', 'neutral'): 366, ('first', 'positive'): 249, ('second', 'negative'): 72, ('second', 'neutral'): 158, ('second', 'positive'): 99, ('third', 'negative'): 156, ('third', 'neutral'): 348, ('third', 'positive'): 270}
d = {}
for k,v in o.items():  #Iterate over your dict
    if k[0] not in d:
        d[k[0]] = [{"sentiment":k[1] , "value": v}]
    else:
        d[k[0]].append({"sentiment":k[1] , "value": v})
print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'second': [{'value': 72, 'sentiment': 'negative'}, {'value': 99, 'sentiment': 'positive'}, {'value': 158, 'sentiment': 'neutral'}], 'third': [{'value': 156, 'sentiment': 'negative'}, {'value': 348, 'sentiment': 'neutral'}, {'value': 270, 'sentiment': 'positive'}], 'first': [{'value': 57, 'sentiment': 'negative'}, {'value': 366, 'sentiment': 'neutral'}, {'value': 249, 'sentiment': 'positive'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for (label, sentiment), value in input_dict.items():
       out[label].append(dict(sentiment=sentiment, value=value))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.